# BeautifulSoup get href after find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im scraping through a vendor link directory. Ive created a soup & isolated all the data I want using the find_all method. However the string I need is nested further within the soup. I understand that find_all returns a list but I need to further distill the list to get what I need. Thanks for the help because Im about to chuck my laptop across the room. Below is my current code.

Im new to the coding world with a decent understanding of Python but only a basic understanding of Beautiful Soup.

```
URL = get(https://www......) # importing the url I want to work over
soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text, 'html.parser') # making the soup
IsoUrl = soup.find_all('a',class='xmd-listing-company-name') # Isolates the tags of the links I need.
```

This is more or less where I get stuck. From the above isolation I get a list composed of the following. Below is only one item of the list.

```
<a class="xmd-listing-company-name"href="/rated.company.html" itemprop='url><span itemprop='name'>Company</span></a>'
```

There are 10+ of the above strings in the list. I want to scrape out '/rated.company.html' from each string & append them to a list to iterate through.

Any guidance is greatly appreciate. If I need to clarify anything please let me know

Comment: Just add href=true should work

IsoUrl = soup.find_all('a',class='xmd-listing-company-name', href=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply loop on the results of `find_all`  and extract the href like below :

```
results = [iso['href'] for iso in IsoUrl]

# >>> ["/rated.company.html", ...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Had been attempting something similar (based on other forums) to no avail. Your approach worked exactly as I needed. Thanks again

Comment: you're welcome! you were not so far from the solution, check this [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) to have an idea of others ways